# Calling a function causes error with "fprintf"

Tags: c

```
while(output_read == false)
{
    ...
    fscanf(input_filep, "%s", &output_file);
    output_filep = fopen(output_file, "w");
    
    if(output_filep != NULL)
    {
        output_read = true;
    }
    else
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: output file name not in file");
        input_filep = NULL;
        free(input_filep);
        free(output_filep);
        return 1;
    }
}

fprintf(output_filep, "testing opening output, success\n");

int i;
int **boardpp;
boardpp = (int**)malloc(sizeof(int) * num_rows);

if(boardpp == NULL) 
{
    fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: Array of pointers for 2-D array could not be allocated\n");
    fprintf(output_filep, "ERROR: Array of pointers for 2-D array could not be allocated\n");
    free(boardpp);
    return 1;
}

for(i = 0; i < num_rows; i++)
{
    boardpp[i] = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * num_cols);

    if(boardpp[i] == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: Array storage could not be allocated\n");
        fprintf(output_filep, "ERROR: Array storage could not be allocated\n");
        free(boardpp[i]);
        return 1;
    }
}

// this block of code is causing error with printing to output file

if(init_type == 1)
{
    InitBoardRand(boardpp, num_rows, num_cols, initSeed);
}
else if(init_type == 2)
{
    InitBoardChecker(boardpp, num_rows, num_cols);
}
else if(init_type == 3)
{
    InitBoardAllWhite(boardpp, num_rows, num_cols);
}
```

In this block of code toward the middle where it says "fprintf(output_filep, "testing opening output, success\n");", it prints the message to the output file no problem, as long as none of the three functions in the last if-else block get called. If I comment out the three if-else statements at the end, nothing gets printed to output_filep but the program still runs, it just doesn't do anything. Very baffled rn because how can calling a function AFTER the print statement cause "fprint" to not work???

I tried commenting out the last three if-else statements. I have tried defining the functions before AND after main(). From what I've noticed, as long as the functions don't get called, the fprintf statement works fine.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: `&output_file` should just be `output_file`. Arrays automatically decay to pointers in argument lists, you don't need `&` before it.

Comment: Symptoms like this usually indicate that one of the functions is causing undefined behavior and corrupting memory.

Comment: `free(output_filep);` is wrong. You should not free memory that you didn't allocate with `malloc()`. Pointers returned by `fopen()` will be freed by `close()` if necessary.

Comment: Although in this case it's innocuous. You only do that when `fopen()` returns `NULL`, so there's nothing to free. Why do you do `free(input_filep)` immediately after `input_filep = NULL;`?

Comment: Compile your program with `-fsanitize=address` and use `valgrind` to detect memory corruption problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
boardpp = (int**) malloc(sizeof(int*) * num_rows);
```

Comment: Also: [Should I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/should-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: @Chris no idea what it does or why it works but it does. I've been at this assignment for weeks now so I just wanna get it working lol

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

Avoid allocation calculation mistakes.
Size to the referenced object, not the type.

Note: In C, casting `malloc()` results not needed.

```
// int **boardpp;
// boardpp = (int**)malloc(sizeof(int) * num_rows);  // wrong size

int **boardpp = malloc(sizeof boardpp[0] * num_rows);
```

Answer (score 0):

Chiming in regarding *why* you're not seeing any output in your file when your final `if` conditions are run. As a few commenters have highlighted, there are a few errors in your code which could be leading to an abnormal program termination (e.g. via segfault). I'm assuming your file is opened via `fopen(..., "w")` or similar. In this case, writes to the file may be buffered by the kernel **even if your string contains a newline**.

If your program terminates abnormally, any buffered writes may be dropped, meaning you will not see your content appear in your file. This differs from the behaviour of streams like `stdout` which will [flush when a newline is reached](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716296/why-does-printf-not-flush-after-the-call-unless-a-newline-is-in-the-format-strin).

As a minimal reproduction of this:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

static inline void segfault()
{
  volatile int *mem = NULL;
  *mem = 42;
}

int main(void)
{
  FILE *output = fopen("output.txt", "w");
  fprintf(output, "Here's some content\n");
  segfault();
  return 0;
}
```

Compiling and running this on my system, I observe that my `output.txt` file gets created, but no content will be written to it. If I remove my `segfault()` call, then my file will contain what I expect it to. If I enable buffering with `setbut(output, NULL)`, then on my system I observe the file now contains content, even after abnormally exiting.